# Unspent transaction I need some help

Tags: transactions, blockchain

I had a business send me BTC to my exodus wallet.  The transaction is confirmed but about half of the transactions including mine say unspent.  It's been 4 days now.  Can I do anything to help the process?

Answer (score 1):

If the transaction is confirmed, the process is done.  "Unspent" just means you haven't spent the coins yet.  But you can do so whenever you wish.